# How & where to add debugging symbols for Visual C++ OpenCV project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, opencv

I've set up an OpenCV C++ project in Visual Studio 2012. To get it working I have use various project property pages to

1. Additional Include Directories: $(SolutionDir)..\Libs\OpenCV\2.4.6\include
2. Additional Library Directories: $(SolutionDir)..\Libs\OpenCV\2.4.6\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)
3. Additional Dependencies: various files including `opencv_highgui246d.dll`
4. Post-Build Event, Command Line: copies over the DLLs and lib files and some sample content thus:

   xcopy /y $(SolutionDir)..\Libs\OpenCV\2.4.6\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)*.dll $(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
   xcopy /y $(SolutionDir)..\Libs\OpenCV\2.4.6\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)*.lib $(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
   xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)opencv-logo.jpg $(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
   xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)sample.wmv $(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\

The lines of code I'm trying to debug are more-or-less the same as those in the sample code given for the `VideoCapture` OpenCV class here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
```

but I am opening a file

```
VideoCapture cap ("sample.wmv");
if (FileExists("sample.wmv"))
{
    OutputDebugString("File exists\n");
}
else
{
    OutputDebugString("File does not exist\n");
}
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout <<"Failed to open camera" << endl;
    OutputDebugString("Failed to open camera\n");   
    return -1;
}
```

Something's going wrong so I want to check what the properties are on `cap` by setting a breakpoint on the line `if(!cap.isOpened())`. But if I try to examine `cap` in the locals window in Visual Studio 2012 I get the error:

"Information not available, no symbols loaded for opencv_highgui246d.dll"

I'm unfamiliar with setting up C++ projects in Visual Studio (I've been using mostly C# for years now); what do I need to do to enable this debugging? Do I have to build OpenCV myself (and if so what output should I use where) or are there more files I can copy over and include in my build?

Comment: The debug symbols are in .pdb files. If you have opencv_highgui246d.pdb then copy it to the same folder as the DLL. If you don't have it then you need to build the DLL to get the symbol file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- problem: you're using the *prebuild* libs that come with 2.4.6, you'll be able to debug *your own code* but you can't dive into the opencv libs ( like highgui246d.dll ).
- reason: the pdb files needed  for that are not supplied ( think of it , that would blow up the download to the gigabyte range )
- remedy: if you really need to dig into the opencv libs while debugging, you'll have to recompile them ( cmake and all that jive) as this will actually generate the needed pdb files

Comment: Thanks @berak; needless to say I cannot persuade OpenCV to build but that is [another story](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19439670/575530).

Comment: yea, just looking at it ;)

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong there - just trying it out to see if the fix works, but meetings keep getting in the way!

Comment: @berak Hi ! actually I am also having the same broblem `opencv_world300d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file` Do I need to build **OpenCV** from  sources.