# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express - compilation error

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, compiler-errors, qt-creator

All compiled code cause:

```
'Start.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Start\Debug\Start.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Start.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Start.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Start.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Start.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Start.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[8496] Start.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have Windows 7. How to fit it?

Comment: It looks like a normal execution.

Comment: I don't see the error. This looks normal. If you want all the symbols for the OS, you'll need to add them (although I've never needed that).

Comment: The PDB file shouldn't cause you're program to invoke a compilation error; this looks normal. Perhaps you're expecting the console to hold open which won't happen if you don't use `ctrl+F5`. Could that be it?

Comment: As my fore-commenters wrote: there is no visible error - you might want to debug your application and find the real error.

Comment: So what means - Cannot find or open the PDB file?

Comment: This question looks very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954821/cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file-in-visual-studio-c-2010.

Comment: You have two choices.  1) Ignore those messages as they are not errors, and it's unlikely you'll ever need symbols for those dll files.  2) Setup Visual Studio to download the symbols from Microsoft's Symbol Server.  I don't have 2010 installed anymore, but the option is under Debugging->Symbols in 2012 and 2013.  You might consider upgrading since you're using Express already, and the new ones are just as free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDB stands for Program Database. It's the file needed for debugging the code of a particular library or executable. In your case the debugger can't find PDB files for several system DLLs being loaded by your program, which means that you can't debug the code of these DLLs. And that is perfectly fine unless you want to dig into system code (very few people do). You can still run and debug your own program.

If you don't want the console window to close immediately after execution, you can run your program by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> instead of <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging these system libraries is usually not necessary, so you will probably not need the debug symbols for them. Thus these are not really errors, just ignore them :)