# OpenCV on Visual Studio 2012, MSVCP120D.dll missing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I've followed an excellent guide from a user on here how to use openCV with VS2012 and everything seems OK until I run the program where I encounter these messages from debug.

```
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\OPENCV_TEST\x64\Debug\OPENCV_TEST.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_core2410d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[1228] OPENCV_TEST.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

I'm aware that it seems to be trying to load the .dll files for VS2013 as it's trying to open the vc12 bin, but I've checked my paths and they're all vc11. I'm a complete amateur, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you add "vc12" folder to your path/bin/libs/sth.else environment variables?!?

Comment: @Micka - I added it to my environment variables, but deleted it again after I realised vc12 was linked to VS 2013

Comment: did you restart your OS (or at least relog the user) after changing environment variables?

Comment: @Micka - that worked so far as I don't get that error any more, but I now get a whole list of .dll missing messages; e.g 

'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_TEST.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: Never had that problem, but maybe that's because you've compiled 64 bit and try to launch on 32 bit system (Win32)? Could you compile (64 bit) and launch any other code yet?

Comment: although its not the same VS version, try this posting and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954821/cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file-in-visual-studio-c-2010

Comment: @Micka - I believe I am compiling with 64 bit. At the start of the project I went to build > config manager > platform > x64. When I build the code it says successful, but when I run it (simple opening an image code), all I get is a blank grey window. I've not tried any other code yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file  tells you to ignore those "missing PDB" warnings for system dlls. Is there any other error?

Comment: @Micka I followed the advice from your previous link - although there's still a couple of PDBs that don't load, the code now works and the picture loaded. Many thanks for the help - that was a bit of a slog! If you want to add an answer, would be happy to vote/accept.

Comment: Restarting actually solved the problem for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have set **Path** for OpenCV libraries

Open the **Property pages** of the solution.

Select **Release** configuration in **Configuration manager**

Click on **Linker** and select **Input**

edit **Additional Dependencies**

add the following:

opencv_ts300.lib

opencv_world300.lib

Click Ok and Click Apply and run the code. 
It should  work.

[image]