# 'cannot find or open the pdb file' Visual Studio C++ 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++builder

I just downloaded VS 2013 Community Edition and I wrote my first app. When I run it it shows in the output section:

```
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[11196] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What is the problem? I checked my code on many sites so I know that the problem is not in my code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: **See Also**: [Error Message : Cannot find or open the PDB file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15937707/1366033)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try go to Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers", Visual Studio will download PDBs automatically.

> PDB is a debug information file used by Visual Studio. These are
>   system DLLs, which you don't have debug symbols for.[...]

See [Cannot find or open the PDB file in Visual Studio C++ 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954821/cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file-in-visual-studio-c-2010)

Comment: I used this answer to add a path to my ARM build of the Qt 5.6.1-1 framework and traced into the root cause of a crash with full Qt symbol support.

Comment: `Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Microsoft Symbol Servers` in VS2015

Comment: @NickDesaulniers it is in that location for VS2017 as well.

Comment: I tried this and now VS keeps asking me the location of dozens of cs files, like threadpool.cs and so on. I  unchecked it again but VS keeps nagging me with this. How do get rid of this ?

Comment: its taking too much time for loading the symbols from the windows sym server, @GuidoG clean and rebuild the solution, don't know might get work for you.

Comment: Also, to gain some performance, uncheck it again once you have your PDB's downloaded.

Answer (score 37):

No problem. You're running your code under the debugger, and the debugger is telling you that it doesn't have debugging information for the system libraries.

If you really need that (usually for stack traces), you can download it from Microsoft's symbol servers, but for now you don't need to worry.

Comment: You forgot this: `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> enable "Microsoft Symbol Servers" -> OK`

Answer (score 18):

Working with VS 2013. Try the following

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> Module Load
>   Messages -> Off

It will disable the display of modules loaded.

Comment: This is not a solution. It just disables display info.

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me. Go to **Tools-> Options -> Debugger -> Native and check the Load DLL exports**. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

There are no problems here this is perfectly normal - it shows informational messages about what debug-info was loaded (and which wasn't) and also that your program executed and exited normally - a zero return code means success.

If you don't see anything on the screen thry running your program with CTRL-F5 instead of just F5.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I thought I'd share in case it helps anyone: what is most likely the problem is simply that your Debug Console (the command line window that opens when run your project if it is a `Windows Console Application`) is still open from the last time you ran the code. Just close that window, then rebuild and run: `Ctrl + B` and `F5`, respectively.