# MVC 5 dnx.exe error messages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have just started learning ASP.NET - MVC 5 and followed quite a few Pluralsight videos on creating these websites.

The problem I have encountered in my Visual Studio 2015 is, that when I am building my app I can see a lot of the following messages under my Output window:

```
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Host.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Loader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\dnx451\Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\dnx451\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource\4.0.0-beta-23516\lib\dotnet5.2\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.DesignTime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'NewWebApp'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors\4.1.1-beta-23516\lib\portable-net45+win8\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Also I can see, that my Website is loaded much slower than the website that presenters have in the video and I believe it is because of the above mentioned error.

When I run `dnvm list` command under my command prompt, this is the result that I can see:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                      Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                      -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          C:\Users\Robert\.dnx\runtimes
```

Should I change anything under my Visual Studio setup in order to get rid of these error messages, or are these normal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954821/cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file-in-visual-studio-c-2010

Comment: You are using ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET MVC 5, so don't choose the wrong tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages are normal. You're attaching the debugger, and for every module it tries to load the symbols. It just tells you that the symbols are not available.

Comment: Is there a way, how to load those symbols?