# c++ Start Without Debugging output statements

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am rookie in C++, I have my project successfully running in console application when I press "Start Without Debugging"

But when I press "Start Debugging" I get following statements in Output area:

[image]

Could you tell me what these errors means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find or open the PDB file in Visual Studio C++ 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954821/cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file-in-visual-studio-c-2010)

Comment: @Petras, what about this issue? If the answer is helpful for you, you could mark it, if not, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> > Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Generally it would be related to the symbols loaded.

(1) Please enable the Symbols Server Under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.
[image]

(2)Load the assembly manually in the debug Module windows.

(3) Run VS as the admin, Tools-> Options -> Debugger -> check the Load DLL exports(Native Only).